# How to save the original value of what pointer initially points to

Tags: c++

New programmer here... Any help would be appreciated...

In my example below how would I preserve the original value at : 0x4000000 so that once I do:
*(int*)(0x4000000) = 900;
I can still have the original value that was at 0x4000000 before I changed it to 900 or whatever value I decide to set there....

```
int apples = *(int*)(0x4000000);   // lets say that after doing this apples is assigned the value of 10(meaning 10 apples)
   // now how do i backup this original of value 10...
*(int*)(0x4000000) = 900;  // set the apples to 900 and go on...
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, you already have _backed up_ the value in `apples`?

Comment: Are you somehow thinking of `int * apples = (int *)(0x4000000);`, so that `apples` always points to the fixed memory location?

Comment: problem is when i go to printf apples it gives me 900. But what I want is the value initially at 0x4000000.Not the value I set at 0x4000000 aftewards(which is 900).

Comment: @NotATree Don't try to post code samples in comments, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27579769/edit) instead please.

Comment: Here is some help: you already have the original value backed up in the `apples` variable!!!

Comment: @NotATree Don't write something like _[SOLVED]_ in your title, that's what the accept mark is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, after you code `apples` == 10 and `*(int*)(0x4000000)` == 900

if you had done

```
int *apples = (int*)(0x4000000);
```

then at the end `*apples` would have 900.  you could save the 10 by doing

```
int apples_save = *apples; .
```

like this

```
int *apples = (int*)(0x4000000);
int apples_save = *apples; .
*(int*)(0x4000000) = 900;
```

now `*apples` == 900  and `apples_save` == 10 .